# View crossing multiple databases, but a query only using one is slow

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, execution-plan, view

Given a view like this example, crossing multiple databases in the same database cluster, with each database having a **unique** INSTANCE_NO.

Please note that each database can be split using the INSTANCE_NO
Also, each table has only about 100 rows.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[VI_MULTI_DUMMY]  AS
SELECT 1 AS [INSTANCE_NO], [T].[B1] AS [V1] ,[DESC_1] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [V1_DESCR] FROM [HUB_1].[DBO].[TA_DUMMY] AS [T] WITH(NOLOCK)
UNION ALL   SELECT 2 AS [INSTANCE_NO], [T].[B1] AS [V1] ,[DESC_1] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [V1_DESCR] FROM  [HUB_2].[DBO].[TA_DUMMY] AS [T] WITH(NOLOCK)
UNION ALL   SELECT 3 AS [INSTANCE_NO], [T].[B1] AS [V1] ,[DESC_1] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [V1_DESCR] FROM  [HUB_3].[DBO].[TA_DUMMY] AS [T] WITH(NOLOCK)
UNION ALL   SELECT 4 AS [INSTANCE_NO], [T].[B1] AS [V1] ,[DESC_1] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [V1_DESCR] FROM  [HUB_4].[DBO].[TA_DUMMY] AS [T] WITH(NOLOCK)
```

I have a huge performance problem for a query that only accesses one database:

```
--> 0 sec
SELECT 3 AS [INSTANCE_NO], [T].[B1] AS [V1] ,[DESC_1] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [V1_DESCR] , ... [HUB_3].[DBO].[TA_DUMMY] AS [T] WITH(NOLOCK)

--> 5-7 sec
select T.* from VI_MULTI_DUMMY AS T  WITH(NOLOCK) where  INSTANCE_NO = 3 OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

I've used RECOMPILE, NOLOCK, ... and I'm out of idea's, who can help me?

**EDIT : SOLUTION** 
A solution as stupid as the problem :
Go to each database it's properties--> Options--> Automatic.
Set 'Auto Close' to false

Comment: This looks like a partitioned view, which makes me wonder if you have the appropriate check constraints on your primary key in each table. Also, stop using `NOLOCK`.

Comment: Can you do sp_refreshview and run the query ?

Comment: sp_refreshview didn't work, 
not to mention the view is rebuild after each newly added database.

Why can't I use NOLOCK? woudn't it work faster & have less problems with the replications on it?

Are you telling me move from a view with a dynamic INSTANCE_NO to a table like this? 
With a different default INSTANCE_NO CHECK?
     CREATE TABLE [TA_DUMMY]
     (
 [V1]     INT     NOT NULL,
 [DESC_1]    VARCHAR(255)  NULL,

 [INSTANCE_NO]   INT     DEFAULT(1) CHECK([INSTANCE_NO] = 1)
    )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Anwser :**

Go to each database it's properties
--> Options
--> Automatic.

Set 'Auto Close' to false

Answer (score 1):

Never mind,

I just went with sp_executesql

Performance issue are gone, readability gone

```
SET @myInst = '[db2Name]'
SET @sqlReplaced = REPLACE('myQry','{@myInst}',@myInst)

EXECUTE sp_executesql
@statement                  = @sqlReplaced,
@ParmDefinition             = @ParmDefinition,

@clientNo                   = @clientNo,
@lastTransactionDate                = @lastTransactionDate,
@msInstanceNo               = @msInstanceNo, 
@dateFrom                   = @dateFrom , 
@dateUntil                  = @dateUntil
```